# Issue with axes scaling when applying a filter to plt.imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, gaussian, imshow, histogram2d

I am trying to apply a gaussian filter to a 2dhistogram but the y-scale isn't fitting properly when I use my input data.

If I run an example dataset it works fine. This is an example using random data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np

x = random.sample(range(80), 10)
y = random.sample(range(80), 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(x,y)
z,x,y,p = plt.hist2d(x,y, bins = 40, range = np.array([(0, 80), (0, 80)]))
plt.imshow(z.T, interpolation = 'gaussian', origin = 'lower', cmap = 'jet', extent = [0,80,0,80])
```

Output: [image]

However, when I try to generate the same plot from my input data it doesn't work. See below.

```
x = [29160, 30420, 30840, 31680, 31920, 32040, 33000, 33300, 33480, 34200]
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(x,y)
z,x,y,p = plt.hist2d(x,y, bins = 40, range = np.array([(29000, 35000), (0, 10)]))
plt.imshow(z.T, interpolation = 'gaussian', origin = 'lower', cmap = 'jet', extent = [29000,35000,0,10])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation. https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

use `aspect='auto'` and a suitable interpolation within your `plt.imshow()` function. Since your image aspect is very skewed, you want to rescale it to the axis size.

Comment: Thanks mate. I tried `aspect = equal`!. I thought it could have been something to do with the extent.